# Is it possible to accept data through multiple forms in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, webforms

A client developed an entertainment website using Wordpress as the back end. He wants to be able to have users enter data into two different forms; one form for users to enter events and another form for users to enter entertainment venue information. Has anyone solved this before?

What's the correct design pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 2 page templates to hold the 2 forms. You may need to add one or two tables to the database to hold the forms values.